# Is the 'key_content' field safe to use in the OCI Python SDK?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-python-sdk

This primarily directed at the Oracle SDK Dev team but docs say to post non-issue questions here.

When passing a config to the OCI SDK, the code accepts a value in the 'key_content' field that can contain the private key details rather than needing a file on disk.  This is very useful if we need to obtain the key programmatically from another source.   However, this is not documented on [readthedocs](https://oracle-cloud-infrastructure-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html) so I am concerned this may be deprecated or otherwise removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

feel free to use it. It will not be deprecated (at least for current), it's been used inside SDK a lot.